# Disable typewriter function if already typing

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I have a jQuery function that emulates a typewriter effect, I have it being called on the `.mouseup()` handler function.

Now if the user releases the `.mouseup()` 2 times really fast the typewriter effect doubles up and types something like this: "ttyyppeewwrriitteerr eeffffeecctt".

It would be nice to know when it is done typing and disable mouse interaction while it is typing.

Here is my jQuery function: ( http://jsfiddle.net/MARm2/1/ )

```
//Typewriter Effect
$.fn.Typewriter = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = { animDelay: 50 },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);
    $.each(settings.text, function(i, letter){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.html($this.html() + (letter!='\n'?letter:'<br />'));
        }, settings.animDelay * i);
    });
}
```

Here is the `.mouseup()` handler function:

```
$('#game_howto').mouseup(function(e) {
    $('#game_howto_slide1').Typewriter({
        animDelay: 50,
        text: 'Typewriter effect'
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In order for someone to answer this question properly, you're going to need to elaborate a bit more on what this "typewriter" functionality is exactly.

Comment: @adamb It's pretty clear, but here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/MARm2/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark the element with the data attribute while you're typing and unmark it when you're done. Your modified code:

```
$.fn.Typewriter = function(opts){
    var $this = this,
        defaults = { animDelay: 50 },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

    $this.data('typing', true); // we are typing!

    $.each(settings.text, function(i, letter){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.html($this.html() + (letter!='\n'?letter:'<br />'));

            if (i == settings.text.length  - 1) {
                $this.data('typing', null); // this is the last letter, we are done typing!
            }
        }, settings.animDelay * i);
    });
}

$('#game_howto').mouseup(function(e) {
    if (!$('#game_howto_slide1').data('typing')) { // only run if not typing
        $('#game_howto_slide1').Typewriter({
           animDelay: 50,
            text: 'Typewriter effect'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a busy flag

```
var Typewriter = (function(){
    var busy=false;
    return function(opts){
        if(busy){
           ...       // nothing
        }
        else{
           busy = true;
           ...       // something
           busy = false
        }

    }
})();
```